# Erro na validação da form

Tags: php, html, mysqli

O que eu preciso de fazer é quando  o email não for válido envês do alerta em javascript queria mostrar uma mensagem por cima da form em questão que mostrasse que o email era inválido!

**CÓDIGO HTML**

```
           <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" 
   placeholder="Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Introduza um email 
 válido"REQUIRED />

          <div class="validation"></div>
        </div>
```

**VALIDAÇÃO PHP**

```
 if(isset($_POST["contact"]))
  {

 if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

 $novocontacto = "insert into contacto(nomecompleto, email, assunto, 
  mensagem) VALUES ('$nomecomp', '$email', '$assunto' , '$mensagem')";
 $novocontacto_run = mysqli_query($conn,$novocontacto);

 echo 
'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!") 
 </script>';
  }

  else 
 {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Email inválido")</script>';
  }

    }
```

Comment: Use um validador de formulário em JavaScript - https://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/

Comment: Ando meio perdido agora porque estou tentando ter meus forms seguros e não sei se estou fazer da maneira correta! Eu penso que preciso mesmo filtrar com php para poder depois inserir meus valores na base de dados!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor opção seria usar o [.validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) um plugin do jquery como mencionado acima, esse plugin permite que você especifique um conjunto de regras para a validação contento mensagens e validação em tempo real, este [exemplo](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) ilustra bem isso.

Você pode setar o .validate para enviar seu formulário por ajax se tudo estiver correto.

Comment: Parece-me uma boa maneira! Mas esclareça minha dúvida esse metódo vai proteger meu form contra possível sql injection ?

Comment: Visto que não vai permitir inserir coisas inválidas! Eu tenho outro metódo de filtração em php também que elimina os caracteres especiais!

Comment: @AlmostDone até onde eu sei não, mas eu faria isso via php, eu usaria o PDO para fazer as operações sql em segurança.

Comment: @AlmostDone Eu usario o pdo prepare() para evitar sql injection, mas ele não vai proteger tudo esse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection tem uma resposta que simula uma injeção sql e como configurar o pdo para proteger completamente.

Comment: Mas também posso usar o mysqli procedural ou não terá o mesmo efeito a nível de segurança?

Comment: @AlmostDone sim porém você vai ter que fazer toda a validação, se eu não me engano ele é mais complexo em termos de criação de um sistema seguro, mysqli_real_scape_string (acho que é essa a função) não deve ser suficiente, eu daria preferência para o pdo até por causa do desempenho dele que é superior.

Comment: Esse artigo explica bem as vantagens e desvantagens de mysql, mysqli e pdo: https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/diferencas-mysqli-versus-pdo-versus-mysql-benchmark-para-comparacao-de-desempenho-seguranca-e-conversor-que-funciona-em-2016-e-2017/amp/%3ftrace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Penso  que é opção do programador porque a nível de segurança penso que sejam ambos do mesmo nível e velocidade também! Pelo menos a maneira mysqli que ele está fazendo igual a do PDO é igual a  que estou usando!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, uma solução possível sem restruturar todo o código é adicionar uma div em cima do form e o php retornar o script adicionando a mensagem.

código html

```
// ...
<div class="mensagem"></div>
// formulário
// ...
```

validação php

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.querySelector(".mensagem").innerHTML = "email inválido"; </script>';
```